# Create column counts from the first occurrence of value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I want to create a calculated column using DAX that will count from the first non zero occurrence in the column and will restart when the ID changes. Column 'index' is the result I am after.

For example:

| id | occurence | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | 0 | 0 |
| A1 | 1 | 1 |
| A1 | 0 | 2 |
| A1 | 0 | 3 |
| A2 | 0 | 0 |
| A2 | 1 | 1 |
| A2 | 0 | 2 |
| A2 | 0 | 3 |

Have been playing around with using RANKX, FILTER, and EARLIER functions but cannot get it to work for my entire data set.

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to make it work in your data set, because it does not contain any fields that define order. To identify "id changes", you need to first define how these ids must be sorted. Otherwise, their sequence is completely random.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this should be to create a measure that follows the following logic:

```
MeasureForYou = 
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Sales[CustomerKey] ),
    IF (
        MIN ( Sales[OrderDate] )
            = CALCULATE ( MIN ( Sales[OrderDate] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sales, Sales[CustomerKey] ) ),
        1,
        BLANK ()
    )
)
```

**or**, this measure counts each occurrence for the specified column indicated at the beginning of `sumx` (values).

```
sumx(values(yourtables), if(measure as condition) = 1, 1, blank())
```